# Sortable DIV with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging

I have a HTML page structured with bootstrap v4.3.1 and has nested **divs** including slides > slide > row > scroll-div > portfolio-item.

I would like to apply react **sortable** controllable component to portfolio-item so user can drag up and drop to a row above like in the example [here](https://reactjsexample.com/a-react-component-built-on-top-of-sortable/).

*Pastebin ref to html structure* - https://pastebin.com/ng7T1akF

```
<div class="row">
                       <div class="scroll-div">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
                                <a class="portfolio-link"  href="https://www.addictinggames.com/">

                                    <img class="img-fluid portfolio-img" src="img/Addicting_games.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                    <img class="icon" src="img/logos/addicting-games.png" alt="">
                                    <span class="item-title">Addicting Games</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

How do I integrate react sortable into my html page in pastebin?

Comment: Is there also a question? I do not know why the demo page doesn't hide the dragged item from the list while dragging the item :-s

Comment: I've updated the question and I hope to integrate the sortable react controlled component to the portfolio-item div's so i can drag them when using mobile reason being the jquery ui and jquery libraries wont allow me to drag using mobile touch

Comment: I don't have experience with the library. Only thing I can say is, I used React-dnd with success, for achieving the same result.

Comment: How do I go about it implementing it ?